# Csv file consumption, ignoring commas inside the path

Tags: csv, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a PowerShell that exports some data, and I am trying to do some BI with it, I have the problem that some paths have ','.

Below in yellow is the path:
[image]

How can I indicate in powerquery to separate on delimiter ',' but ignore if they are part of the path?

Comment: you should enclose every "field" in "" then ...

Answer (score 1):

You can't and you need to fix this at source by choosing a different delimiter or enclosing fields in quotes. Although PQ is powerful, it isn't magic and does need to work from some base logic.

Comment: Can this be marked as solved?